# Jenkins "SonarQube plugin" is not reading argument "/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=" to pass unit test result file path generated by MSTest plugin

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, jenkins-mstest

[image]I am using MSTest for unit test in jenkins. I am able to successfully integrate MSTest plugin with Jenkins. it's performing Unit tests and generating a TestResults.trx file at specific location. 
Now, I want to pass that file to SonarQube. So, I can see code coverage result on SonarQube. Currently I have Sonar configured without code coverage. It's getting all data without unit tests result. To pass the file to sonar, i found this details on Sonar documents here https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772

I tried to pass arguments **/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=%CD%\MSTestResults.trx** in Sonar. It didn't work. I have tried multiple times by changing directory and other stuff, It didn't help. 
Does anyone ever did this before? Why SonarQube plugin in Jenkins is not reading this arguments!!!

I can see in build details that it's reading the agrument which i am passing and it's looking for a file at right location. Still it's not doing anything with that file. as per build details below,

`[Test] $ D:\jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarQubeScanner_MSBuild\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:Test_Jenkins /n:Test_Jenkins /v:1.0 /d:sonar.host.url=http://xxxxxxx:9000 ******** /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=D:\jenkins\workspace\Test\TestResults.trx
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.3.2`

**For second option**

I have also tried to use Visual Studio Code metrics ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Visual+Studio+Code+Metrics+Plugin ) to get code coverage. I am able to setup it in jenkins. i can see Code coverage result in jenkins, when i tried to pass that file to sonar, it didn't work.

I am getting metrics.xml file as output with coverage result. I tried to feed it to Sonar by passing argument `/d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportesPaths="${WORKSPACE}\metrics.xml`

still it's not working. I am getting result of code coverage as you can see below by visual studio code metrics plugin.[image]

Please advice!

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the sonar properties along with the path of the MSTest results file path w.r.t Jenkins workspace

Comment: How do you pass the argument? In your Jenkins job configuration or in SonarQube Server UI?

Comment: @Suresh - I edited post with screenshot of MSTest and Sonar properties. I have tried multiple ways to pass path in Sonar properties. It didn't work

Comment: @JulienH.- I am passing arguments from Jenkins in build configuration as you can see in above screenshot i edited in post.

Comment: Try like this /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=%WORKSPACE%/TestResults.trx or $WORKSPACE/TestResults.trx

Comment: @Suresh - Just tried both, Didn't work.

Comment: Provide the location of the TestResults.trx file with respective Jenkins workspace.

Comment: @JulienH.- any idea? I couldn't find any solution yet. please advice, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two concepts. In SonarQube, you can provide test execution report, so that you track in SonarQube some statistics about tests execution (number of tests, % success, duration, ...). This is done by passing one of the properties `sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths`, `sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths` or `sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths`.
To be honest this is an historical feature, with a very limited interest.

More interesting is to provide test coverage report to SonarQube. This is done by passing one of the properties `sonar.cs.ncover3.reportsPaths`, `sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths`, `sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths` or `sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths` depending on the tool you are using to measure coverage.

Comment: can you tell me where can i find more details on second concept, how to feed test coverage report to SonarQube? I am using MSTest to perform unit test.

Comment: never mind, I found doc. on test coverage result. https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770

Comment: Okay, as per documents,I will have to use any tool from the list of 4. When i looked into jenkins plugin store, I found this plugin called "Visual Studio Code metrics" as per document it's saying use Visual Studio Code Coverage https://plugins.jenkins.io/vs-code-metrics. is this the same tool?

Comment: I tried second option by using Visual studio code metrics plugin. i am facing same issue with it also as you can see in edited original post. Please suggest if you have anything.